# Symfony2 error using EventListener to redirect user, GetResponseEvent expected

Tags: php, symfony, events, fosuserbundle, event-listener

I try to implement a redirection after registration using a EventListener but I don't know how to trigger it corectly. I have this error

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to
UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener::onRegistrationConfirm()
must be an instance of UserBundle\EventListener\GetResponseEvent, 
instance of Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event given
```

Here is my `RegistrationConfirmListener::onRegistrationConfirm()` method :

```
public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $url = $this->router->generate('standard_user_registration_success');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Here is the declaration of my service in service.yml file :

```
rs_user.registration_complet:
    class: UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
    arguments: [@router]
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'fos_user.registration.completed'}
```

Here is the ->dispatch method in my controller :

```
$dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED);
```

I don't understand how or where I can pass an other argument to my Event, and how it will actualy redirect my user ... I'm actualy not sure it will work at all.